# Gratis Windows/Linux Ada compiler (IDE) for MIPS target

Tags: windows, gratis, ide, ada

I am looking for a gratis Ada compiler – at least; preferably an IDE, including debugger – to run on a MIP processor (specifically [this](https://onion.io/store/omega2-pro/) SBC). Preferably with Ada 2012 support (SPARK, or similar static code analysis  a bonus).

Preferably a Windows app, but I can live with Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the Debian repository for options. Debian stable (*stretch*) seems to have a (slightly outdated) cross-compiler + IDE available out-of-the-box:

- [`gnat-6-mips-linux-gnu`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gnat-6-mips-linux-gnu) or [`gnat-6-mipsel-linux-gnu`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gnat-6-mipsel-linux-gnu) and
- [`gnat-gps`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gnat-gps).

Debian testing (*buster*) seems to contain more recent versions:

- [`gnat-8-mips-linux-gnu`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gnat-8-mips-linux-gnu) or [`gnat-8-mipsel-linux-gnu`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gnat-8-mipsel-linux-gnu) and
- [`gnat-gps`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gnat-gps).

Please note that I did not test this. Moreover, it seems that the board you reference is build around a Mediatek MT7688 SoC which contains an embedded MIPS 24KEc processor. I'm not sure which endianess the processor uses: big (`mips` target) or little (`mipsel` target).

Comment: Welcome aboard and thanks very much for your  help. I will dig into this.